Can't use ipdb: WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR)
I have ipdb.set_trace() in my python code. When running the python script, I get the ipdb shell, but it throws the warning:
WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR)

Warning message aside, I'm unable to use ipdb. It either doesn't catch what I'm typing, or catches the prompt I typed one step before, sometimes concatenates half of current prompt with half of the previous prompt etc.
Using pdb in place of ipdb works fine.
I am connected to a remote server through VSCode, and am running the script in VSCode's terminal.
versions:
python==3.9.18
ipython==8.18.1
ipdb==0.13.13


I encountered the same problem. In my case, setting the number of processes running the distributed training script to 1 resolved it.
